# Set Message-ID of sent mails aren't the same to received mails. (Java Mail)

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail, icalendar

I'm sending ical invitations with java mail. Receiving and answering these requests work fine.

Now I want to track the replies to the sent invitations by their Message-ID.

 I set the Message-ID of the sent invitations like this:

```
    protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
        setHeader("Message-ID", messageID);
        setHeader("UID", UIDString);
        setHeader("ContentID", "blabla");
    }
```

and use this method here:

```
    //updates so set attributes don't get overwritten
    message.updateMessageID();

    //send mail
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

The received invitation displays my Message-ID when I look it up under Message Options(Outlook), but if I reply to it, Outlook generates its own Message-ID, so I'm unable to match the sent invitations to their replies.
It seems to me Outlook is throwing away my additional information,my UID and ContentID get lost too.
 Does anyone have an idea how I can tell Outlook to use my given Message-ID? Or is there any other ID which is unique for the sent and received mails?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to work with the Thread-Index header. It corresponds to the PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX MAPI property - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583.aspx

If you send a valid thread index, Outlook is supposed append an extra 5 bytes on a reply. You can then extract the original thread index from the reply.